# Implementing audio app notification in Android

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

The purpose of application is to play some radio stations via url streaming using exoplayer. The problem encountered is that when the app is running and the notification starts there are 2 different streams playing one by my button press from the radio UI and one by the notification.

My question is how can I make it so when I press a button on the UI it changes the the stream on the notification player as well.

P.S. I have tried importing one player however that proved from mainactivity.java by calling it a static however that causes a memory leak and the stream stop in the foreground service.

I used the notificationPlayerManager(exoplayer) from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8

Main Activity class:

package-----------etc

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import org.atsevdev.radioromania.MyServices.*;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE";

    //initialising variables
    public static final String DigiFm = "http://edge76.rdsnet.ro:84/digifm/digifm.mp3";
    public static final String radio_zu = "http://live.romanticfm.ro:9123/radiozu.mp3";
    public static final String Radio_popular = "http://mp3.radiopopular.ro:7777/;stream.mp3";
    public static final String Eur_fm = "http://89.37.58.103:8000/europafm_mp3_64k";
    public static final String radio_rom_acc = "http://stream2.srr.ro:8000/;stream/1";
    public static final String PROFMurl = "http://edge126.rdsnet.ro:84/profm/profm.mp3";
    public static final String radiobuchuresti = "http://89.238.227.6:8032/\n" +
            "Title1=Bucuresti FM\n" +
            "Length1=-1\n" +
            "Version=2";
    public static final String impactfm = "http://89.39.189.159:8000/";
    private PlayerView playerView;
    public SimpleExoPlayer player;
    public boolean clickCheck = false;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerView=findViewById(R.id.playview);//playview id xml into private variable
        Intent playService =  new Intent(this, MyServices.class);
        Util.startForegroundService(this, playService);




    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,
                new DefaultTrackSelector());//instantiating new player instances
        playerView.setPlayer(player);//xml player to view

        //creating datasource
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "RadioRomania"));



        //extracting stream url
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(PROFMurl));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource0 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radiobuchuresti));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource1 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(impactfm));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource2 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radio_rom_acc));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource3 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(Eur_fm));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource4 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(Radio_popular));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource5 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radio_zu));
        final ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource6 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(DigiFm));




        //start video player
        FloatingActionButton stop = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.stopPLAY);
        FloatingActionButton bt = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.profm);
        FloatingActionButton bt0 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.rad_buc);//buchuresti
        FloatingActionButton bt1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.impactfm);//impact
        FloatingActionButton bt2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_ro_acc);
        FloatingActionButton bt3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.europafm);
        FloatingActionButton bt4 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.radpopular);
        FloatingActionButton bt5 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.Radiozuu);
        FloatingActionButton bt6 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.DigiFm);


        //using onClick methods to choose radio station
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //ini profm
               clickCheck = true;
               player.prepare(mediaSource);
               player.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);


               }
        });
        bt0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //ini impact
                clickCheck = true;
                player.prepare(mediaSource0);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);




            }
        });
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v){ //ini radio ro acc
                    clickCheck = true;
                    player.prepare(mediaSource1);
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);

                }
        });
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){ //ini radio ro acc
                clickCheck = true;
                player.prepare(mediaSource2);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);

            }
        });
        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //ini profm
                clickCheck = true;
                player.prepare(mediaSource3);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);

            }
        });
        bt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//ini radio popular
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.prepare(mediaSource4);


            }
        });
        bt5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//ini radio popular
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickCheck = true;
                player.prepare(mediaSource5);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);


            }
        });
        bt6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//ini radio popular
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        //stop stream here
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//ini radio popular
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();


        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
```

service class:

package ---etc

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import org.atsevdev.radioromania.MainActivity.*;



public class MyServices extends Service {


    private SimpleExoPlayer player1;
    private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;
    public boolean clickCheck = false;


    //importing urls from main
    public String  DigiFm = MainActivity.DigiFm;
    public String radioZU = MainActivity.radio_zu;
    public String europaFM = MainActivity.Eur_fm;
    public String radio_acc_ro = MainActivity.radio_rom_acc;
    public String radio_bucuresti = MainActivity.radiobuchuresti;
    public String impactFM = MainActivity.impactfm;
    public String radiopopular = MainActivity.Radio_popular;
    public String PROfm = MainActivity.PROFMurl;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        final Context context = this;

        player1 = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "RadioRomania"));


        //////////////////////Media Sources/////////////////////////////////
       final  MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(DigiFm));
      final  MediaSource mediaSource0 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radioZU));
       final MediaSource mediaSource1 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radiopopular));
      final  MediaSource mediaSource2 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(europaFM));
      final  MediaSource mediaSource3 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radio_acc_ro));
      final  MediaSource mediaSource4 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(PROfm));
      final  MediaSource mediaSource5 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(radio_bucuresti));
      final  MediaSource mediaSource6 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(Uri.parse(impactFM));
        player1.prepare(mediaSource);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource0);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource1);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource2);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource3);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource4);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource5);
        player1.prepare(mediaSource6);
        player1.setPlayWhenReady(clickCheck);


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
                context, "Channel ID", R.string.app_name, 0,
                new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
        );
    playerNotificationManager.setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNotificationStarted(int notificationId, Notification notification) {
            startForeground(0, notification);
            clickCheck = true;

        }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId) {
    stopSelf();
    clickCheck = false;
    }
});
playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player1);
}
public int onStardCommand(Intent intent, int flats, int stardId){

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
    player1.release();
    player1 = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have found an answer. For anyone else looking bind the main activity to the service.

In that process I have used this method to bind the player from the service:

```
public SimpleExoPlayer getPlayer1()
{
    return player1;
}
```

Then call it in your main:

```
player = myServices.player1;
```